# How to create a hole in a group?

Tags: sketch-app

I have a complex group :
[image]
[image]

I want to replace the screen of the iPhone by a "hole": when I export the group to a `.svg` file, I would like the screen to be a transparent area.

I would prefer a solution with Sketch but I will also be interested by solution that uses other software on the exported image.

---

EDIT:
I am not able to use the subtracted area as a mask.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Sketch with masks.

Below your current layers:

- Create one rectangle larger than the phone's outline.
- Create another above it the size of the screen (you can duplicate the screen element to do this).
- Set them both to no fill, no border.
- With both of those layers selected, use subtract (either the subtract button, or Layer > Combine > Subtract).
- Next, with the resulting Combined Shape selected, choose Layer > Use as mask.

When you export a png of the result the screen will be an empty space.

Comment: Thanks.
I have edited the question. Can't manage to use it as a mask.

Comment: @Colas - your mask layer needs to be below the other layers. It masks layers above it rather than below it (I know, odd given the name, but this is pretty standard behaviour for masks so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ).